# Как приблизить изображение по координатам мышки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Хочу сделать на сайт приближение картинки при наведении, как это реализовано в aliexpress, ниже прикреплю пример, хотел узнать есть ли видео или[image: введите сюда описание изображения] какие-то библиотеки по этой теме?

Answer (score 2):

Зачем библиотеки? Несколько строчек css и mousemove event listener

```js
const imageSize = { width: 1920, height: 1080 };
const image = document.querySelector('.image');

image.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  const rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  image.style.setProperty('--x', (rect.left - event.clientX) * (imageSize.width - rect.width) / rect.width);
  image.style.setProperty('--y', (rect.top - event.clientY) * (imageSize.height - rect.height) / rect.height);
});
```

```css
.image {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ahjI.png) 100% 100% no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.image:hover {
  background-size: auto;
  background-position-x: calc(var(--x, 0) * 1px);
  background-position-y: calc(var(--y, 0) * 1px);
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```